# Contour integral of $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ over the positively oriented circle with radius $\frac12$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have tried the residue theorem since the only problem lies at $0$ since $1$ is outside the circle . I get $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$ with $f(0)=-1$ and so I get that the integral is equal to $-2πi$. Something feels wrong since he suggests splitting it in to $\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z}$. I dont get why the residue theorem wouldnt apply though.Any answer is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. However, if you split your fraction like that, you get the correct answer in a more elementary way. Using that approach, you get (assuming that $\gamma(t)=\frac12e^{it}$, with $t\in[0,2\pi]$)\begin{align}\int_\gamma\frac1{z(z-1)}\,\mathrm dz&=\int_\gamma\frac1{z-1}\,\mathrm dz-\int_\gamma\frac1z\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi i\left(\operatorname{wind}(\gamma,1)-\operatorname{wind}(\gamma,0)\right)\\&=2\pi i(0-1)\\&=-2\pi i.\end{align}So, the residue theorem is not needed at all. All you need to know is Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: i tried doing it like that as well but for some reason i get stuck on the 1/(z-1) part . For the 1/z i apply the z=(1/2)*e^it where t lies from 0 to 2π

Comment: I have added more details to my answer. Is it clear now?